# Register values in container in base class on construction

Tags: c++, constructor

My goal is to register objects on creation in a container. The goal is that a property can not be created without being registered in a container. I started with the following design (Property will have a protected constructor, omitted here because i want to focus on another detail).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Property
{
    std::string mID;
};

class Base
{
public:
    Property createProperty(std::string name) {
        mPropertyContainer.emplace_back(Property{std::move(name)});
        return mPropertyContainer.back();
    }
private:
    std::vector<Property> mPropertyContainer;
};

class Derived: public Base{
    Property mVerySpecial = createProperty("Very Special");
    Property mGlutenFree = createProperty("Gluten Free");
};
```

I know that the construction order enforces that `mPropertyContainer` as a member of Base is initialized before any members of `Derived`. So `mPropertyContainer` is a valid vector.
But `createProperty` will change that vector. The code compiles without warnings with gcc.

My questions are: **Is this well defined behavior? Is it permitted to change members of the base class within the initialization of the derived class? If not, how would i design something like that?**

I tried to find the answer for that problem in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor. But other than the specified construction order i did not find a quote about changing members of base in the initialization of derived. Maybe i just missed that part.

Comment: why not? "I know that the construction order enforces that mPropertyContainer as a member of Base is initialized before any members of Derived" thats right, so what else could go wrong?

Comment: Usually it is a bad idea to call overridable methods in constructors. But if you declare your createProperty to be virtual final, you should be OK.

Comment: btw the code you posted does not compile

Comment: @rhobincru one should not call virtual mehtods during construction but thats not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline initialization of members is actually done at the time of the constructor. And are initialized in order of declaration.

Since base classes are initialized before members, the `Base::mPropertyContainer` will have been initialized by the time the local `Derived` members are initialized.

So this should be fine.

Comment: Is being initialized sufficient? I knew as much but was not sure. I hoped someone could point out the part of the standard that defines such behavior.

Comment: @Mehno An object can't be initialized if it isn't constructed. And once an object is initialized, it can be fully used for all intended purposes. If you really want quotes and sections from the specification, then please add the `language-laywer` tag.

Comment: I was unaware that this tag exists. The only benefit i see is to attract the attention of people that might have the necessary expertise (which might be what i want). I do not really care for the exact quote. Just something with more substance than "should be fine".
If i understand you correctly it is permitted to change any non const initialized value at will once it was initialized. Hence this is a special case.